# How to increase the size of a figure

Tags: includegraphics

I am working on a paper. There is a specific figure that I need to modify. The scaling of the figure is incorrect right now.

Here is a sample of the code for the figure

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=1.5, clip,width=0.45\linewidth]{figure/MVC_BEFORE_AND_AFTER1.png}
  \caption{WORD MATCH MVC DIGAGRAM BEFORE AND AFTER}
 \label{fig:WordMatchMVCDiagramBeforeAndAfter} % If you want to label your figure for in-text references
\end{figure}
```

Expected: The figure size should be increased by 1.5 the original size.

Actual: The figure size does not change when I adjust the scale.
[image]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: the scale is ignored as you over-write it with `width=0.45\linewidth` which re-scales it to that width. (also `clip` isn't doing anything as you are showing the  entire figure, so effectively you just have `[width=0.45\linewidth]`

Comment: `\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{figure/MVC_BEFORE_AND_AFTER1.png}`, but you should be sure, that image after scaling wil fit on the page ...